# Python split string with delimiter

Tags: python, string, parsing, split, yaml

I'm trying to put it inside an array but without keeping the comments that begin with # and without the first "-".

```
      - https://site1                                                             # site1
      - https://site2                                                     # site2
      - https://site3                                                           # site3
      - https://site4                                             # ssite4
```

I don't know if I have to remove the end of each line before or after having put it inside the array.
If I put in inside an array with removing spaces etc, I have something like that:

```
['-https://site1#site1', '-https://site2#site2', '-https://site3#site3', '-https://site4#site4']
```

And I would like to only keep the websites.
Expected result:

```
['https://site1', 'https://site2', 'https://site3', 'https://site4']
```

Comment: Hard to show where you went wrong without your existing code.

Comment: If you iterate over the lines then get the value of `line.split()[1]` (where `line` is a single line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with `regex`:

```
import re 
  
def findUrlFromString(string): 
  
    regex = r"(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))"
    url = re.findall(regex,string)       
    return [x[0] for x in url] 
      
string = """
   - https://site1                                                             # site1
      - https://site2                                                     # site2
      - https://site3                                                           # site3
      - https://site4                                             # ssite4
"""
print(findUrlFromString(string))
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://rextester.com/LEHDE94008

Another way with **list comprehension**,

```
list_of_urls = ['-https://site1#site1', '-https://site2#site2', '-https://site3#site3', '-https://site4#site4']
result = [i.split('#')[0].lstrip('-') for i in list_of_urls]
print(result)
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://rextester.com/VNW41814

Comment: Second method with list works perfectly, thanks

Comment: @Michael003 glad it helps you somehow :)

Answer (score 2):

`url.lstrip(“-“).split(“#”)[0]` Should work

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple approach. given your input strings as a list:

```
raw_list = ["- https://site1                                                # site1",
       "- https://site2                                                     # site2",
       "- https://site3                                                   # site3",
       "- https://site4                                             # ssite4"
      ]
```

I created an output list to store the sanitized strings. Then iterate through the list and remove all unwanted characters

```
def sanitize_string(raw_string):
    #strip all leading and trailing whitespace
    raw_string.strip()
    #remove leading "-" character
    if raw_string[0] == "-":
        raw_string = raw_string[1:]
    #remove comment from line
    if "#" in raw_string:
        raw_string = raw_string.split("#")[0]
    #once again remove leading and trailing whitespace
    return raw_string.strip()


raw_list = ["- https://site1                                                             # site1",
           "- https://site2                                                     # site2",
           "- https://site3                                                           # site3",
           "- https://site4                                             # ssite4"
          ]
sanitized_list = list()

for entry in raw_list:
    sanitized_list.append(sanitize_string(entry))

[print(x) for x in sanitized_list]
```

There are fundamental limitations to this approach. If a string happens to start with "n-", the leading strip will not work correctly. I believe you would want to look for the "https://" or any other web header as the start of the string instead of assuming the format.